# Unable to copy or delete or rename files in Debian

Tags: debian, permissions, clipboard

I use the latest version of Debian (9.4). Recently I realized that I'm unable to copy and paste (or cut and paste), rename or delete any file on my laptop at all. I can't even download any file it always fails. I even tried opening a directory as root but still, I can't do anything on my files.

I noticed that this is happening only for hard disk partitions that are in `/media` directory. Everything is fine where I try working with my files anywhere else.

I executed `mount` command and got this result:

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=4019144k,nr_inodes=1004786,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=806088k,mode=755)
/dev/sda7 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=30,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=8593)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/anbox-installer_17.snap on /snap/anbox-installer/17 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_4407.snap on /snap/core/4407 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_4206.snap on /snap/core/4206 type squashfs (ro,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/118 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=806084k,mode=700,uid=118,gid=123)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=806084k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/strangify/Milad type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda6 on /media/strangify/Work Disk type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda8 on /media/strangify/01D2D0A75AE15B80 type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda5 on /media/strangify/Softwares and Courses type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda3 on /media/strangify/Music and Wallpaper type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda2 on /media/strangify/Windows 10 type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe the file system is mounted as read-only. Check it  with the command `mount`.

Comment: @jcbermu How should I do this?

Comment: Open a terminal window and type the command. If you can't intepret the result please paste it - AS TEXT - into your question.

Comment: Okay, looking at the mount options I see that several of your disks mounted under `/media/` (probably your dual-boot windows partitions) are mounted read-only. Are those the directories you can't seem to write to?

Comment: Yes, only disks in `/media` directory have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause here is that your filesystem (How many partitions do you have?) is mounted read-only.

This can sometimes happen automatically when something goes badly wrong at the hardware level, and the kernel remounts the filesystems read-only in order to try to preserve the data.

As a quick check, type `dmesg | grep read | grep only`

If this is the case, it's possible that a reboot will fix things; if not, chances are you have a serious hardware issue, and I recommend checking if your backups are okay.

Comment: I tried and got this: `[    1.434092] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 12288k`

Comment: I found out what was causing this problem. I think the last time I was using Windows it didn't turn off properly and because of that, the file system had mounting problems. So I switched to Windows for a couple minutes and switched back to Debian and now everything works fine.

Comment: Yeah, if windows doesn't shut off properly the filesystems are marked as 'dirty' when linux tries to mount them, so it mounts them read-only just in case there's an actual problem.